# Shopify cart/update.js endpoint not updating the correct lineitem

Tags: shopify, cart, shopify-api

There are several items in the cart with the same variant id, but different properties and discounts. I noticed that when I make a post request using the lineitem keys to the cart/update.js endpoint, it is not updating the correct line item. It's just updating the first item that has the variant id..
Any reason why this could happen?

For example, there are multiple lineitems with the variant id "40072319336547".
When I run this

`jQuery.post(window.Shopify.routes.root + 'cart/update.js', "updates[40072319336547:62a477719b1f798b23f1ce16199c1668]=3" );`

It's not updating the line item with key "40072319336547:62a477719b1f798b23f1ce16199c1668". Just some other lineitem with the variant id 40072319336547.

Answer (score 0):

In that case (multiple lines with same variant id in the cart) is better to use `change.js` instead of `update.js`: https://shopify.dev/api/ajax/reference/cart#post-locale-cart-change-js

I'm doing like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post", url: "/cart/change.js", data: [
        {"quantity": 2, "line": 0},
        {"quantity": 4, "line": 1},
    ], dataType: 'json'
});
```

You see that I don't use the `variantId` but I'm using the line index. The downside of this approach is that if you need to apply a change to all the same variant ids you need to know which lines have to be changed. But that can be done reading the respone from `cart.js`